# scipy.stats.binned_statistcs to calculate standard deviation

Tags: python, scipy

the documentation for binned_statistics doesn't mention whether or not it has an inbuilt function to calculate standard deviation. Looking at the source it seems that it does. I was just wondering whether anyone knows if there is a reason why it is not being mentioned in the documentation?

I was looking at github and the commit that added std to the function is from 2012 so surely they must have had the time to add it to the documentation since then.

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains the same functionality as scipy.binned_statistics, and more:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
g = npi.group_by(keys)
g.mean(values)
g.std(values)
g.median(values)
g.max(values)
# etc
```

Note that the expensive part is creating the group_by object; subsequently calculating various statistics is very efficient.